# How to assign comment id?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am making comment system and now I want to insert comments to database and I am confusing that on what basis to assign specific comment_id.
Suppose we have multiple dives of images with comment system.if someone comment on image then how can we assign a specific comment id on that specific image.and if other user comment on same image then how can he found that image comment_id so the comment save in right direction.
we have many images and comment system for that image.
My english is bad may be you understand what i want to say.

Comment: yes unique id for comment bt i am not talking about auto increament id suppose i have table and it has id, coment_id, user_id, body and id is auto_increment

Comment: Add the image id in a column in the comment table.

Comment: Sorry I completely misunderstood the question, James' answer seems viable.

Comment: my english is not so high :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a number of different tables in the database

**table: comments**

```
|comment_id | userID | name | comment | (for example)
  1         50     James  test 
  2         50     James  test 
  3         50     James  test
```

**table: images**

```
|image_id | link |
  1      example.com/images/image1.png
  2      example.com/images/image2.png
  3      example.com/images/image3.png
```

**table: comments_on_images (to make the table's purpose clear)**

```
|id | comment_id | image_id
  1        1          2
  2        2          2
  3        3          1
```

Using this method you can assosciate any number of comments to any images.  You have to query the database using `JOINS` to get all the information you need.

Comment: You don't need to crete a third table. you can put the image_id directly into the comments table